# split 1200 page document into 500 pages and then the remaining

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

I am new to the Unix world, and I have text files that contain 1200 pages identified by `^L`.   Is there an effective way to break of that file to have 2 separate files of 500 pages each and then a 3rd with the remaining pages.

I'm thinking something like read the file to locate the first `^L` then count the next 500 output to temporary file, continue reading to create the next temporary file or is there a more effective way?

My script is written in bash running [MKS toolkit](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/).

Answer (score 7):

Assuming every page starts with `^L` (a literal <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>):

```
awk '/^L/ { p++ } (p-1) % 500 == 0 { f = FILENAME "-page-" p ".txt" } { print > f }' file.txt
```

This would count the lines with `^L` and if the count minus 1 is a factor of 500 (page 1, page 501, page 1001 etc.) it will set the variable `f` to a filename to output the following text into.

The `^L` in the `awk` code is *not* the two characters `^` and `L`, but a literal <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> (you may type this with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>). You may also use `\014` in place of this.

For a small test document `test.txt`:

```
^L
page 1
^L
page 2
^L
page 3
^L
page 4
```

... and changing 500 to 2 for testing, this generates two files, `test.txt-page-1.txt` and `test.txt-page-3.txt`, each containing two lines (page marker and text) from the input file.

`test.txt-page-1.txt`:

```
^L
page 1
^L
page 2
```

`test.txt-page-3.txt`:

```
^L
page 3
^L
page 4
```

---

The files that are to be parsed apparently have a header before the first page marker. This header needs to be ignored.  The following variation on the above `awk` command does this:

```
awk '/^L/ { p++ } (p-1) % 500 == 0 { f = FILENAME "-page-" p ".txt" } p > 0 { print > f }' file.txt
```

By restricting the output to when `p` is greater than zero, we require that at least one page marker has been parsed before outputting anything.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I attempted it and got a syntax error:  + awk // { p++ } {p-1} % 500 == 0 { f = test.txt "-page-" p ".txt" } { print > f } file.txt 
awk: Syntax error  Context is:
>>> /^L/ { p++ } {p-1} % <<

Comment: @gizmo You have `{ p - 1 } % 500` instead of `( p - 1 ) % 500`.

Comment: @ Kusalananda   I changed the {} to ()  and got the same syntax error ........ + awk // { p++ } (p-1) % 500 == 0 { f = ${test.txt} "-page-" p ".txt" } { print > f } file.txt 
awk: Syntax error  Context is:
>>> /^L/ { p++ } (p-1) % 500 == 0 { f = ${ <<

Comment: @gizmo `FILENAME` should be `FILENAME`. It's a special variable in `awk` and contains the name of the current input file.

Comment: @ Kuslananda    sorry I think I may be missing something else ....... + awk // { p++ } (p-1) % 500 == 0 { f = FILENAME "-page-" p ".txt" } { print > f } test.txt 
awk: line 0 (NR=1): output file "": The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @gizmo Could you post the exact command you're using in the next comment please?

Comment: @roaima I was thinking this too, but wasn't sure if they would have been removed in the error message.

Comment: @roaima Absolutely no worries whatsoever.

Comment: awk '/^L/ { p++ } (p-1) % 500 == 0 { f = FILENAME "-page-" p ".txt" } { print > f }' test.txt        ->  the ^L is typed here but I used ctrl +  ctrl +l  in the script

Comment: Your input file, does it have a `^L` on the first line? (it should have).  If it doesn't I could come up with a workaround, but that will be later tonight.

Comment: input file does not have it on the first line, it does have it after the report details, give or take 60 lines down. a ^L separating each page, the last line in the file also does not have ^L

Comment: @gizmo See addition at the end of the answer.

Comment: the new update did not error out, however I cant seem to find the output file(s) to verify anything, the original file has not been modified in any way

Comment: @gizmo The output files _should_ be called `test.txt-page-1.txt` and `test.txt-page-501.txt` etc... I wonder if it's a Windows filename limitation or something that is playing in.  Change `f = ...` to just `f = p ".txt"`. That will give you numerical filenames with a `.txt` suffix.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option. This one anchors on the <kbd>^L</kbd> character (I assume it's a single character, octal `014` rather than the two literals <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd>). For your source data file called `original.txt` it will split each page into its own file. From there you can concatenate them into the required chunks:

```
# GNU csplit
csplit --prefix='page_' --digits=4 original.txt $'/\014/+1' '{*}'

# MKS csplit
csplit -f 'page_' -n 4 -k original.txt $'/\014/+1' '{9999}'

# Concatenate the required sets of pages together
cat page_{0000..0499} > part_1.txt
cat page_{0500..0999} > part_2.txt
cat page_{1000..9999} > part_3.txt

# Tidy up
rm page_????
```

Comment: See the [MKS manual for `csplit`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/csplit.1.asp)...

Comment: It also seems to lack `bash` (not certain about what shell it uses). So brace expansions may not work. (later: my bad, it has `bash`)

Comment: @Kusalananda ah, yes. I haven't used non-GNU `csplit` for too long. Added. Thanks.

Comment: hi thanks, this worked, it split the files at the formfeed as expected, however to combine them into sets of 500, the cat command did not work. it created 3 empty (o byte ) files even though the input files were avg 5kb

Comment: @gizmo if you're using `bash` as described in your question this will have worked. Make sure you're using `{`...`}` and not `(`...`)` braces. What is the _exact_ command you tried and what error message did you get from it?

Comment: running MKS toolkit on windows server 2012 in a bash shell, MKS version 9.6 patch2, shell identified at top of script is #!/bin/sh, Error identified in the logs is - + cat page_{0000..0499} 
cat: page_{0000..0499}: The system cannot find the file specified. 
+ cat page_{0500..0999} 
cat: page_{0500..0999}: The system cannot find the file specified. 
+ cat page_{1000..9999} 
cat: page_{1000..9999}: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @gizmo that's `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`. They are different shells. Change the first line of the script to be the path to `bash`, as described in your question, and it'll work.

Comment: shell line was changed #!/bin/bash, and still same error and noted above

Comment: @gizmo how _exactly_ are you running the code?

Comment: right in the bash command window of the MKS tool kit, command line, execute script

Comment: @gizmo how do you execute it? Please write _exactly_ what you type. This is important.

Answer (score 1):

If good old gnu split can be used:

```
split -t '^L' -l 500 bigFile part_
```

- `-t '^L'`  - unit separator is <kbd>^L</kbd>
- separate in files with 500 units
- in bash, to introduce <kbd>^L</kbd> we have to type <kbd>^V</kbd> <kbd>^L</kbd>. It is also possible to use the octal notation:`split -t $'\014' ...`

Comment: [`split` on MKS](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/split.1.asp) does not have `-t`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Oops: thanks. I didn't notice MKS  (and ignore what that dialect is)...

Comment: Since we're using `bash` we can use `$'\012'` to represent the `^L` character, and then you can side-step the necessity of explaining the `^V`+`^L` keys

Comment: @roaima, thanks cool! (the $'\012' or in this case $'\014' is new to me!)

Answer (score -2):

Is this a text file or a more complex (PDF, WORD etc)? Maybe you should give the builtin `split` command a try. it works something like this

```
split -l1000 textfile
```

This will split into your text file into multiple files with 1000 lines each.

Comment: This would ignore the embedded `^L` page markers in the text file unfortunately.

Comment: The OP has not specified a fixed page length so I don't think this can work.

Comment: Hi the input file is a formated unix file for printing, there is text/whitespace, the file is for payment summaries, each page is separated by the formfeed ^L followed by more formatting, line counts can not work since there is different line counts per page due to white space